# How do I count the number of cells for certain columns that have data?

Tags: r

I have a data frame called `df` that looks like this:

```
name score1 score2 score3
Joe     1      NA    3
Jane    NA     2     3
```

How do I make a `TOTAL_NonEmpty` column that counts the number of non-empty cells in `score1`, `score2` and `score3`?

Comment: `sum(!is.na(df[, c('score1', 'score2', 'score3')]))`?

Comment: `df$TOTAL_NonEmpty <- rowSums(!is.na(df[-1]))`

Comment: Yeah, I missed the 'row-by-row' part. Good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R,

```
df$TOTAL_NonEmpty <- rowSums(!is.na(df))

## For specifically those columns:
df$TOTAL_NonEmpty <- rowSums(!is.na(df[, c('score1', 'score2', 'score3')]))
```

Should give you the count of non-missing values for each row.